# How can I create a VSCode snippet from my current selection?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

If I have this code:

```js
do(() => {
  things('many');
  stuff('lots')
});
```

Is there a way in VSCode, to select/highlight that code and convert it into a user snippet to be edited?

It would open the snippets file and enter something like this:

```json
   "": {
        "prefix": "",
        "body": [
            "do(() => {",
            "\tthings('many');",
            "\tstuff('lots')",
            "\t});"
        ],
        "description": ""
    },
```

Ready to have the blanks filled in?

Comment: what if you have multiple indent levels, how much space is 1 indent, if no extension to be found you can write one yourself, be aware of the need to escape `"`

Comment: You could probably write a complex command to do this, but there is this already: https://snippet-generator.app/?description=&tabtrigger=alt%2Bd&snippet=do%28%28%29+%3D%3E+%7B%0A++things%28%27many%27%29%3B%0A++stuff%28%27lots%27%29%0A%7D%29%3B&mode=vscode and https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dkultasev.vs-code-snippet-generator